# How muliti table join in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, join, left-join, inner-join

I want muliti table join.it's show 1 data/show 2 record But really 1 data/1 record.

```
select acl.Person_ID as 'CODE'
,pnr.FullName as 'FullName'
,case acl.persontype when 'normal' then 'normal' end as 'Type'
From tbl_aculog acl left join tbl_PerNR pnr On acl.Person_ID=pnr.Person_ID

union

select acl.Person_ID as 'CODE'
,ps.FullName as 'FullName'
,case acl.persontype when 'blacklist' then 'blacklist' end as 'Type'
From tbl_aculog acl left join tbl_Person ps On acl.Person_ID=ps.NPerson_ID
```

Result:

```
Person_ID |    FullName |    Type
00010132 |  Stin|         normal
00010132 |  NULL |        NULL
00000579 |  Plom |        normal
00000579 |  NULL |        NULL
00001081 |  Watson |          normal
00001081 |  NULL |        NULL
5211080 |   SOPIT |       blacklist
5211080 |   NULL |        NULL
```

**Fields Person_ID & FullName & Type is NULL VALUE.

**I want Result:**

```
Person_ID |    FullName |    Type
00010132 |  Stin|         normal
00000579 |  Plom |        normal
00001081 |  Watson |          normal
5211080 |   SOPIT |       blacklist
```

Thank you very much for your time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `NULL`s from your result, you need to specify `WHERE acl.persontype IS NOT NULL` to ignore empty 'persontype'.

```
select acl.Person_ID as 'CODE'
,pnr.FullName as 'FullName'
,case acl.persontype when 'normal' then 'normal' end as 'Type'
From tbl_aculog acl left join tbl_PerNR pnr On acl.Person_ID=pnr.Person_ID
WHERE acl.persontype IS NOT NULL

union

select acl.Person_ID as 'CODE'
,ps.FullName as 'FullName'
,case acl.persontype when 'blacklist' then 'blacklist' end as 'Type'
From tbl_aculog acl left join tbl_Person ps On acl.Person_ID=ps.NPerson_ID
WHERE acl.persontype IS NOT NULL
```

**Edit 1**

The use of an `INNER JOIN` will remove `NULLS`.

```
select acl.Person_ID as 'CODE'
,pnr.FullName as 'FullName'
,case acl.persontype when 'normal' then 'normal' end as 'Type'
From tbl_aculog acl inner join tbl_PerNR pnr On acl.Person_ID=pnr.Person_ID

union

select acl.Person_ID as 'CODE'
,ps.FullName as 'FullName'
,case acl.persontype when 'blacklist' then 'blacklist' end as 'Type'
From tbl_aculog acl inner join tbl_Person ps On acl.Person_ID=ps.NPerson_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

It's don't result

**More:**

```
Result:

Person_ID |    FullName |    Type
00010132 |  Stin|         normal
00010132 |  NULL |        NULL
00000579 |  Plom |        normal
00000579 |  NULL |        NULL
00001081 |  Watson |          normal
00001081 |  NULL |        NULL
5211080 |   SOPIT |       blacklist
5211080 |   NULL |        NULL
NULL | NULL |        NULL
NULL | NULL |        NULL

I want Result:

Person_ID |    FullName |    Type
00010132 |  Stin|         normal
00000579 |  Plom |        normal
00001081 |  Watson |          normal
5211080 |   SOPIT |       blacklist
NULL | NULL |        NULL
NULL | NULL |        NULL
```

I'm sorry data relate.

to "njk" code result no NULL VALUE but i want show NULL VALUE when not duplicate values​​.

Thank you very much for your time again. :)